# bartik css clone

Tags: 7, theming

I have a Drupal site that uses the Bartik theme, under the `/users` directory.

For the sake of consistency, I'm looking to convert Bartik to a basic non-Drupal CSS theme that I can use on the `/` folder. I only need the header and nav bar.

Anyone ever see anything like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you modify Bartik, the modification itself [must also be GPLv2 or later](http://drupal.org/licensing/faq#q1). If your use case permits this, then read on...

Honestly, your best bet is to use something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see which stylesheets are being added and how selectors are being applied. You would then use the same templates, tags, classes, IDs and CSS rules as Bartik does to duplicate the results, adapting where necessary from there. Drupal themes tend to use classes and IDs extensively, so it probably won't be "CSS only" - your markup does matter. That said, while Drupal themes are obviously meant to work with Drupal, they could be easily adapted for other purposes.

Comment: Does it render different css for different browsers? Meaning is the rules it gives me for firefox the same as ones for IE? I see heavy use of `:after` should I duplicate that too?

Comment: Bartik uses [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to serve different CSS to IE, in addition to the default CSS. Have a look at ie.css (for lte IE7) and ie6.css (for IE6) to see what you'd have to add.